# Narrowing return value of function based on argument

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code

```
type Foo = {
  kind: "foo";
  foo: number;
};

type Bar = {
  kind: "bar";
  bar: number;
};

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

function foobar(arg: FooBar, kind: "foo" | "bar"): FooBar | undefined {
  if (arg.kind === kind) {
    return arg;
  }
  return undefined;
}

declare const a: FooBar;

if (a.kind === "foo") {
  a.foo;  // no error, type is correctly narrowed
}

foobar(a, "foo").foo; // error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Bar'
```

Is it possible to write type signature for `foobar` function, so return value is narrowed according to the `kind` argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract the kinds by using generic parameters to model the types that we want to use as 'variables' across our output types.

In this case I use `ExtractKind<T>` to extract the unions of different kinds of T.

Then we can use `RefineKind<T, K>` - where T is the type with a kind and K is the kind to refine to.

I've wrapped the output result with an undefined check - if you want I can provide an example on how to exhaustively map all types to remove the need for this check but this seems outside the scope of the original question.

Let me know if you need any further explanation on these concepts!

Full example:

```js
type Foo = {
  kind: "foo";
  foo: number;
};

type Bar = {
  kind: "bar";
  bar: number;
};

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

type ExtractKind<T> = T extends { kind: infer K } ? K : never;
type RefineKind<T, K> = T extends { kind: K } ? T : never;

function foobar<K extends ExtractKind<FooBar>>(arg: FooBar, kind: K) {
  if (arg.kind === kind) {
    return arg as RefineKind<FooBar, K>;
  }
  return undefined;
}

const foo = foobar(a, "foo");

if (foo !== undefined) {
  foo.foo; // foo -> number
}
```

Typescript playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBrAlgOwBMAuKAIgDMEyBuTKKuU-AVwFsAjCAJzoF866UJCgAhAIbdkaeniKkyHSbXpLuzdl17oB6IeGjw4EqSiNQAPmMmDh0AKIAPYN3EBjYAGkChADwAVAD5pfygIZwgiAGc0HB9SAgoeKE8oPigAfhSoZggANx5bAygAJQgKAghvIgCAGhTglFDw4EjCGNQ4%20Wz0rNDcgu10ChZ8D1w4fAYENV9UlraYpxd3Lx9fIxNAwIAKSQBzUk3JerkSFIBKGSxcCig97n2AOjPkJBQzq4wsLG4IYBY3CmByg4hiZQq%20Cq62O3HqnkCdCwfHofwBQKgo0I5UqhH4emxbgANpJoG5JlFgKCjggTIJbvdxC8fG8UJRqF96EzGDQsAB6PlQfCIHjcOBwqB2KC4GLk7h-DxEkBCyRigDuEEIOj05PwlOmiBQjDUe3q7LgZAu9LuO0YUAAhO9MUQcVDCJysIwnjyoAKDVAALTBVicHg6IA)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really trying to do here is implement a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  Essentially you write a boolean function with the return type `arg is SomeType` and that tells typescript that if the function is `true` than `arg` must be of type `Sometype`.  And if it's `false` then that means that `arg` cannot be of type `Sometype`.

Here is what that function looks like in your case:

```
function isKind<T extends Kinds>(arg: FooBar, kind: T): arg is Extract<FooBar, {kind: T}> {
    return arg.kind === kind;
}
```

When you use this function inside an `if` statement, you get meaningful information about the type:

```
function testUnknown( either: FooBar ) {
    if ( isKind(either, "bar") ) {
        // we now know that either is Bar
        const barVal = either.bar; // ok
        const fooVal = either.foo; // error
    }
    else {
        // we now know that either is Foo
        const barVal = either.bar; // error
        const fooVal = either.foo; // ok
    }
}
```

I personally would prefer to write `isKind` as a double arrow function so that you could more easily call `isKind("foo")` inside an array.map or other callback, but that's just down to code style and personal preference.

```
const isKind = <T extends Kinds>(kind: T) => 
    (arg: FooBar): arg is Extract<FooBar, {kind: T}> => {
        return arg.kind === kind;
    }
```

Your original `foobar` function can use your `isKind` type guard internally. This is similar to @mbdavis's answer but you don't need to assert the type of `arg` using `"as"` because typescript already understands that the type has been refined.

```
function foobar<T extends Kinds>(arg: FooBar, kind: T): Extract<FooBar, {kind: T}> | undefined {
  return isKind(arg, kind) ? arg : undefined;
}
```

But I suspect that you don't really even need this `foobar` function and can just call `isKind` directly in your code.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA1gSwDsATALigCIAzBCgbixxrnMIFcBbAIwgCcHMAXwFZQkKACEAhr2RpGeImUpcZ9Bat6tOPflmFZR4aPDjTZKU1AA%20kmSMxjoAaSUBnOafMBtAOQESXwBdKAB6UKg2Qnw4QigncmpaGxU1Q0wqKIBjYBi4-DdXEgAeABUoCAAPYAgSDyLiNwA%20AAoZAHNyLxkAGkUSclKASnIOqAKoAFFq3ikc4u7ePtQA5VLBJvlsHCheCGA2XjiOgDpV5CQUVYFBdPCoKQAbGqOpXIA3aAB3KRAoOCoUC%20vHwuUI7SwWVibmA40KSgA%20gi5GUKtVao0oA1mi1VoMhshNgocG1eJ1YAhzCMHmS4VMZnNgAtKb00HioOtNkhNhhtjsdnsDkcae0zkoLlclAJ%20bdMFhMoQcnl4hAYQBVQi4QhwL6EFoVUEACz4XRZsgJvP5%20EB%20oKDRaECNfD6FE0FAJFuJ-LCES%200G1XzwAfihreBuAxtkE3MXv5UMIMKgmgAak85I6I3wTpo6D7-rhYzt44nmKnHumnbwTsxc-c%20Lw4LwvbL%20RBHm5oJbvTh7n6oMGtTqQ2GM5G6aZCzhi7CU2mUKOszm8-XG5OoNOoKW5%20HI9WELWInAC3yoLLZfLsrlYpuEJpUVUanUse5Wh1TWZWezhuRpsBZvNFmWL8NhSKJiAgKgiAgYgthwQVDnyeESFJdo%20lWAkAH4RSgcgwIgqDiBuLAgA)